# JSON with Basic Authentication instead of API key

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have to download data from a REST server and populate tables in SQL. So I have this working, using a test REST server site, that uses an API key. The code below.

var url = "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=a28cb70b31404429bea46b0889ec6697 ";

```
      var currencyRates = CCAP_JSON_Downloader.CCAP._download_serialized_json_data<CurrencyRates>(url);
       // Console.Write();



public class CCAP
    {
        public static T _download_serialized_json_data<T>(string url) where T : new() {
  using (var w = new WebClient()) {
    var json_data = string.Empty;
    SqlConnection DB_CONN_1990 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CCAP_JSON_Downloader.Properties.Settings.DB_CONN_1990"].ToString());
        DB_CONN_1990.Open();

    // attempt to download JSON data as a string
        //for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            try
            {
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url);

                JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json_data));
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                     Console.Read();

                    if (reader.Value != null)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("CAPTURING" + "Path: {0}, Value: {1}", reader.Path, reader.Value);
                        var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_RAW_XML", DB_CONN_1990);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Token_Type", reader.Path);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", reader.Value);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType);
```

So now, I have access to the state REST server, but they use BASIC HTTP authentication. CODE BELOW

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://wccarest.wicourts.gov:443/api/v1/counties?expand=all&api_key");
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0";
            string autorization = "username" + ":" + "Password";
            byte[] binaryAuthorization = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(autorization);
            autorization = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryAuthorization);
            autorization = "Basic " + autorization;
            webRequest.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", autorization);
            var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) Console.WriteLine("{0}", webResponse.Headers);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))

            {
             string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
          Console.WriteLine(s);

            }
```

My question is, I do like how I had it working before. where I can just feed the URL,  var url = "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=a28cb70b31404429bea46b0889ec6697 ";

But now, I can't figure how to get the full URL with the authentication. I have the encryption from the user and password. but it seems I can only pass the base URL, so I always get a Unauthorized error.  How can I submit the URL with the full credentials that I can pass into class CCAP.
First time working with REST servers and etc, so I'm open to any other suggestions or a better way to do this.
Thanks
Rudy

Answer (score 0):

Try use special URL format: http://username:password@example.com/ - this should send the credentials in the standard HTTP "Authorization" header.

For example, https://username:password@wccarest.wicourts.gov:443/api/v1/counties?expand=all&api_key

Comment: Hi fl_int, Thanks for the quick response. I tried that.  Still no auth error.